# Null characters randomly added to string C++

Tags: c++

I have written a simple battleship game in C++. After several iterations of the game, one of the strings in a "Player" object is changed. This change is several null characters are added to the end of the string. Otherwise the rest of the object is untouched. For example if the player type is "cpu", the player type switches to "cpu\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0". I believe the line of code causing the problem is:

```
currPlayer->getStrategy().getNextAttack(nextPlayer->getBoard(1));
```

Here is the code for getNextAttack():

```
int Strategy::getNextAttack(Board enemyBoard) {
    //clear prob board
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        probBoard[i] = 0;
    }

    //reset largest ship
    largestShip = 0;

    //assign largest ship
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Ship currShip = enemyBoard.getShipByCoord(i);
        if(!currShip.isSunk()) { //if ship is still afloat
            if(currShip.getSize() > largestShip) { largestShip = currShip.getSize(); } //reassign largest ship on board
        }
    }

    //assign base prob
    std::vector<int> allPossible;
    //for all horiz coords
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < (10 - largestShip +1); j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < (largestShip); k++) {
                if(!enemyBoard.beenHit((i*10) + j + k) || (enemyBoard.beenHit((i*10) + j + k) && !enemyBoard.getShipByCoord((i*10) + j + k).isSunk())) { //if not hit or if hit but contains a ship that is not sunk
                    allPossible.push_back((i*10) + j + k);
                }
                else {
                    for(int m = 0; m < k; m++) {
                        allPossible.pop_back(); //should delete last element
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            //for all vert coords
            for(int z = 0; z < (largestShip); z++) {
                if(!enemyBoard.beenHit(((j+z)*10) + i)) {
                    allPossible.push_back(((j+z)*10) + i);
                }
                else {
                    for(int m = 0; m < z; m++) {
                        allPossible.pop_back(); //should delete last element
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int p = 0; p < allPossible.size(); p++) {
        probBoard[allPossible[p]] += 1;
    }


    //add improvements based on hits
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            int currCoord = (i*10) + k;
            int leftCoord = (i*10) + k-1;
            int rightCoord = (i*10) + k+1;
            int upCoord = ((i-1)*10) + k;
            int downCoord = ((i+1)*10) + k;
            if(enemyBoard.beenHit(currCoord) && (enemyBoard.getShipByCoord(currCoord).getName() != "") && !enemyBoard.getShipByCoord(currCoord).isSunk()) { //currCoord is a coordinate that has been hit, contains a ship and is not sunk
                if((enemyBoard.beenHit(leftCoord) || enemyBoard.beenHit(rightCoord)) && (enemyBoard.getShipByCoord(leftCoord) == enemyBoard.getShipByCoord(currCoord) || enemyBoard.getShipByCoord(rightCoord) == enemyBoard.getShipByCoord(currCoord))) { //if space to left or right is hit and the same ship
                    //increment only the left and right
                    if(!enemyBoard.getShipByCoord(currCoord).isSunk()) { //ship cannot be sunk as well
                        probBoard[leftCoord] += 25;
                        probBoard[rightCoord] += 25;
                    }
                }

                else if((enemyBoard.beenHit(upCoord) || enemyBoard.beenHit(downCoord)) && (enemyBoard.getShipByCoord(upCoord) == enemyBoard.getShipByCoord(currCoord) || enemyBoard.getShipByCoord(downCoord) == enemyBoard.getShipByCoord(currCoord))) { //if space on top or bottom is hit and the same ship and not sunk
                    //increment only the top and bottom
                    if(!enemyBoard.getShipByCoord(currCoord).isSunk()) { //ship cannot be sunk as well
                        probBoard[upCoord] += 25;
                        probBoard[downCoord] += 25;
                    }
                }

                //if no direct spaces in any direction to hit coord, increment top, bot, left, and right equally
                else {
                    probBoard[upCoord] += 20;
                    probBoard[downCoord] += 20;
                    probBoard[leftCoord] += 20;
                    probBoard[rightCoord] += 20;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //marks odds at 0 if already fired upon
    for(int n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
        if(enemyBoard.beenHit(n)) {
            probBoard[n] = 0;
        }
    }

    //find next best attack coord based on prob board
    int highestValue = 0;
    std::vector<int> highestSpaces;
    for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        if(probBoard[j] > highestValue) { highestValue = probBoard[j]; }
    }
    for(int r = 0; r < 100; r++) {
        if(probBoard[r] == highestValue) {
            highestSpaces.push_back(r);
        }
    }
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
    int randNum = rand() % highestSpaces.size();
    return highestSpaces[randNum];
}
```

Thank you for reading and any help!

Comment: Do you actually expect someone to understand the shown code, when it is a small part of an apparently much larger program, and references classes and methods that are not even shown, at all?

Comment: I guess not. I was hoping that the problem of the null characters being added to the string would be enough for some help. Also I assumed I would be flamed if I posted all of my code? Am I wrong in assuming that? I was just trying to post what I thought was most relevant but I guess I failed miserably.

Comment: The commenters are right, there isn't enough info here to debug the problem.  However, that doesn't mean you can't debug it yourself -- either use a debugger to set a watchpoint such that execution will pause whenever your player-type string is modified, and then check the current stack trace to see who is doing it -- or if you can't do that, you can fake it by writing a function that prints out the current player-type string, and sprinkle calls to that function all around your code; then you can see from your stdout output exactly when the value is changed, and from that infer the culprit.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it will go out of the array bounds at the edges when the row or column is 0 or 9:

```
 probBoard[upCoord] += 20;
 probBoard[downCoord] += 20;
 probBoard[leftCoord] += 20;
 probBoard[rightCoord] += 20;
```

Comment: You're welcome, but pay attention to the comments above on debugging -- learning to debug code is much more useful than someone handing you a fish  :)
... and be sure to check for edge cases in ALL of the places you're using up / down / left / right.